# What would the propagator of the Feynamn diagram for $\bar{q}q \to \gamma \gamma$ be?

Tags: feynman-diagrams, quantum-chromodynamics, quarks

I am trying to draw the Feynman diagram at tree-level for: $$\bar{q}q \to \gamma\gamma $$ but I don't seem to understand what sort of propagator fits this diagram? 
I have seen in some places that a gluon is used as a propagator, but I don't seem to think it is fit for this case.

Comment: The quarks are charged, and, as fermions they have no seagull couplings. So the two photons attach to the hairpin quark line at two points, leaving the propagator to merely be a quark one.

Comment: Like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annihilation#/media/File:Mutual_Annihilation_of_a_Positron_Electron_pair.svg), but with quarks.

Comment: Thank you, I was pretty sure the diagram would be like in the link, but I didn't know that a quark could be a propagator when a quark was also the initial particle

Answer (score 0):

I am haven't studied QCD deeply, but only considering QED interaction, this is the usual particle-antiparticle annihilation.  I don't think chromodynamics mediate in this interaction because there is only photons as a result of the annihilation, at least at low orders.